# Zen Barcode with characters. Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, barcode, zen

[image]

Hi does anyone know how to include the numbers/strings too at the bottom when it draw the barcode?

Here is my code

```
     private void btnGenerate_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Zen.Barcode.Code128BarcodeDraw barcode = Zen.Barcode.BarcodeDrawFactory.Code128WithChecksum;
        pictureBox1.Image = barcode.Draw(textBox1.Text, 50);
    }
```

PS should i save it in a database column and call it there too? Thank you

UPDATE base from sir VVatashi answer. here is the new output.

[image]

But its overlapping the barcode i want it to look something like this:
[image]

Thank you

Comment: If you don't yet know how to use Graphics.FromImage() then keep it simple and put a label underneath the PictureBox.  No point putting a barcode in a dbase, just save the text.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can print text on image with System.Drawing, according to your code:

```
Zen.Barcode.Code128BarcodeDraw barcode = Zen.Barcode.BarcodeDrawFactory.Code128WithChecksum;
var image = barcode.Draw(textBox1.Text, 50);

using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
using (var font = new Font("Consolas", 12)) // Any font you want
using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White))
using (var format = new StringFormat() { LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far }) // To align text above the specified point
{
    // Print a string at the left bottom corner of image
    graphics.DrawString(textBox1.Text, font, brush, 0, image.Height, format);
}

pictureBox1.Image = image;
```

It's a bit unclear how database related to the first part of your question.

**Update.**
Oh, I did not notice that the generated barcode graph is the entire image. In this case, you can draw barcode and text on a larger image:

```
Zen.Barcode.Code128BarcodeDraw barcode = Zen.Barcode.BarcodeDrawFactory.Code128WithChecksum;
var barcodeImage = barcode.Draw(textBox1.Text, 50);

var resultImage = new Bitmap(barcodeImage.Width, barcodeImage.Height + 20); // 20 is bottom padding, adjust to your text

using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(resultImage))
using (var font = new Font("Consolas", 12))
using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
using (var format = new StringFormat()
{
    Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, // Also, horizontally centered text, as in your example of the expected output
    LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far
})
{
    graphics.Clear(Color.White);
    graphics.DrawImage(barcodeImage, 0, 0);
    graphics.DrawString(textBox1.Text, font, brush, resultImage.Width / 2, resultImage.Height, format);
}

pictureBox1.Image = resultImage;
```

Comment: Sir it worked but the number is overlaping the barcode. wait ill post a pic in the question

Comment: @FutureDev, I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Is it readable by a barcode scanner?

Comment: @FutureDev, you can test your output with some web services like http://www.onlinebarcodereader.com/. For now it seems that it generates a valid barcode. Also please stop calling me sir, actually i'm girl.

Comment: Ohhh I am so sorry ma'am!

Comment: @NinaLisitsinskaya Do you have an offer for printing the same bar code without losing quality and in any paper size? I have a similar question you can find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63246342/3929525